# React UI Library Best Practices for React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, components, react-hooks, storybook

Hey I am creating a React UI library with reusable components. All components are function components.

I use storybook for the presentation of the components.

I have a question for components like forms, toggle buttons, select boxes and dropdowns.

What is the best way for building reusable components like these? because you should be able to get values or e.g. a boolean, if the toggle button is true or the dropdown is open, in the parent component.

Should the component itself have a state? Or should the component be stateless and the parent component should manage the state and the function and give it to my library component as a prop? Are there useful examples?

For example my toggle button component:

Library component:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';

export interface IProps {
  onToggle?: (open: boolean) => void;
  onClick?: () => void;
}

const ButtonToggle: FunctionComponent<ButtonSwitchProps> = ({
  onToggle,
  onClick
}: ButtonSwitchProps) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = (): void => {
    setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);
    if (onToggle) onToggle(!dropdownOpen);
  };

  return (
    <SwitchButtonStyle onClick={toggle}>
      {!dropdownOpen ? 'All' : 'None'}
    </SwitchButtonStyle>
  );
};

export default ButtonToggle;
```

And the example usage in Storybook:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import ButtonToggle from './ButtonToggle';

export default {
  component: ButtonToggle,
  title: 'ButtonToggle',
};

export const Toggle: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonToggle onToggle={action('onToggle')} />
  );
};
```

I use the onToggle function in the parent. the action Addon shows the boolean in storybook. The better and working way for a reusable UI library is the usage of the state in the parent component, isn't it? So the UI library has stateless components and when you use the library you have to control the states.

I hope somebody can give me tipps and perhaps an example for some of the listed components, especially a complex reusable dropdown component. Thank you so much.

Comment: I went down a similar path recently: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240828/handling-callback-of-a-react-component-which-uses-a-context
My take away is that you can use states within your library components, but you need to be careful and should call callbacks within effects. If you want to exchange knowledge don't hesitate to get in touch with me.